# Android INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK base.apk is missing after updating to gradle plugin 7.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating gradle plugin from 7.1.3 to 7.2.1, when attempting to build and install our app in AndroidStudio I get the error INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK ... base.apk is missing.

I noticed, that the built apk file is very small (~6 MB instead of ~20 MB).

When switching back to gradle plugin 7.1.3, everything is fine.

I am using Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1.

Comment: have you tried `build>clean project` and `build>rebuild project`?

Comment: @Niraj Yes, I tried all these things.

Comment: try this : ./gradlew clean

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes I did actually. I've added my solution as accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found out that the issue was caused by `testCoverageEnabled true` in my build.gradle buildType. I don't know how and why, and it is not an ideal situation, but removing it, fixed the problem.

**August 16, 2022**

With gradle plugin version 7.2.2 from latest update the problem seems to be **fixed** and I can again build APKs with `testCoverageEnabled true`.

Comment: It also fixed for me..... mind blowing! Now, I need to find out what to do with the `testCoverageEnabled true`

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes Indeed  If you find out something, please let me know.

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes FYI, with gradle plugin 7.2.2 issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: Dont work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

a little late.

There can be multiple possibilities for the issue.

I also faced this issue back in the day.

Fix 1 -> your package name must have '.' eg: com.example.app

Fix 2-> Just remove old APK android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk in the folder

Please do give these a try. I hope your issue gets resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the old debug app and try again after a clean build

- rm -rf android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/
- Invalidate cache and restart
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter run

Answer (score -1):

You can try any one of these

1. HMS toolkit Uninstall it if its installed
2. Invalidate Cache and Restart
3. Delete all build folders and try again.
4. Build > Clean Project

Let me know if you have solved it.

Answer (score -2):

```
To fix the above issue just remove .idea,.gradle folders from project level
```

[image: Project Level]

```
and remove build folder inside app level folder app > build
```

[image: App Level]

```
Rerun the app.
```

Answer (score -3):

Just remove old APK android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk in the folder. that's all. enjoy your coding...